# Perl keyword require is giving strange outcome

Tags: perl

I had a problem where my program was going to infinite loop. I narrowed down the problem and it turned out that **keyword require** was causing that. Hence to understand the problem I wrote a simple hello world program which has the exact file include structure as the bigger program. It has a main file **test.pl** which calls helloWorld from **test2.pm**. test2.pm calls the same routine from **test1.pm**.

Test.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use test1;
use test2;
print "In test\n";
test2::helloWorld();
```

Test1.pm

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
package test1;
use test2;
require "test.pl";
@ISA = qw (Exporter);
@Export = qw(
    helloWorld
    );

sub helloWorld {
print "Hello world: Test1\n";
}
```

Test2.pm:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
package test2;  
use test1;
@ISA = qw (Exporter);
@Export = qw(
    helloWorld
    );

sub helloWorld {
test1::helloWorld();
}
```

This is the output from the program:

```
In test
Hello world: Test1
In test
Hello world: Test1
```

I wish to understand why it printed the output twice? If I comment out 
 #require "test.pl" from test1.pm, it only prints output once.

Test1.pm (require line commented out)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
    package test1;
    use test2;
    #require "test.pl";
    @ISA = qw (Exporter);
    @Export = qw(
         helloWorld
            );
    sub helloWorld {
        print "Hello world: Test1\n";
    }
```

And this is the output now:

```
In test
Hello world: Test1
```

I think if I understand this, I can tackle my real problem. Thanks for any help in this regard :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a perl script executes, the files loaded via `require` and `use` so far are kept in the `%INC` hash, in order to prevent code from being executed more than once, and to prevent infinite mutual recursion. However, you are importing your main script from one of the modules it imports, so it will run once during the import process, and again as the script. Here is the order in which your files are loaded and executed:

1. `test.pl` runs and sees it needs to load `test1.pm`.

   1. `test1.pm` is loaded, and it sees it needs to load `test2.pm`

      1. `test2.pm` is loaded, and it sees it needs to load `test1.pm`, but `test1.pm` is already loaded, so it continues.
      2. `test2::helloWorld` is defined, and `test2.pm` returns.
   2. Back in `test1`, it now sees that `test.pl` needs to be loaded.

      1. In `test.pl`, we try to load `test1.pm` and `test2.pm`, but they have already been loaded via `require`.
      2. Print "In test" and call `test2::helloWorld`
   3. Back in `test1.pm`, define `test1::helloWorld`
2. Back in `test.pl`, print "In test" and call `test2::helloWorld`.

Comment: A much better explanation than mine.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation...it helped a lot. I just wanted to ask one more thing. As you mentioned in step 2.2 it prints `in test" and call `test2::helloWorld". But why does it print and call the function at the first place? Keyword `require` is just used to INLCLUDE the file not to execute it? Is this not correct?

Comment: `require` compiles *and* runs (so does `use`).  `require` does little more than read the file and `eval` the contents, but just once.  Otherwise things like `@ISA = qw(Exporter);` would not happen.

Answer (score 3):

There's a bunch of errors in your code, some related some not.

- The package name should match the name of the `.pm` file, *including the case*.

You're partially getting away with that because you're on a case-insensitive filesystem (OS X or Windows).  `use` and `require` remember if they've already loaded a module, but they remember the filename, not the module name.  When you say `use test1` Perl will be looking for `test1.pm`, but it loads `Test1.pm` instead.  Next time it sees `use test1` it sees it has not loaded `test1.pm` and loads it again... and again... and again.

- The variable to put your function exports into is `@EXPORT` not `@Export`.

Case matters with variable names.

- Requiring `test.pl` in `Test1.pm` or `Test2.pm` sets up a circular dependency.

This is the problem.  Perl has not finished compiling `test.pl` when it loads `Test1.pm` (`use` happens at compile-time).  `Test1.pm` compiles and then is asked to load `test.pl` (`require` happens at run-time) which it does.  Then the original compile of `test.pl` completes and it runs its code.

You have a similar potential problem because `Test1.pm` uses `Test2.pm` and `Test2.pm` uses `Test1.pm`.

This is confusing, it's kinda like time travel.  Let's make it simple: *avoid circular dependencies*.

There's no reason for Test1.pm to use test.pl.  In general, modules should never load a program.

Comment: thanks for your comment...actually file names are same as module names. It just so happened that when I typed the names first letter got capitalized :) I will definitely change Export to EXPORT as that is plain wrong!